# Python: How to use RegEx in an if statement?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code which looks through the files in one directory and copies files that contain a certain string into another directory, but I am trying to use Regular Expressions as  the string could be upper and lowercase or a mix of both.

Here is the code that works, before I tried to use RegEx's

```
import os
import re
import shutil

def test():
    os.chdir("C:/Users/David/Desktop/Test/MyFiles")
    files = os.listdir(".")
    os.mkdir("C:/Users/David/Desktop/Test/MyFiles2")
    for x in (files):
        inputFile = open((x), "r")
        content = inputFile.read()
        inputFile.close()
        if ("Hello World" in content)
            shutil.copy(x, "C:/Users/David/Desktop/Test/MyFiles2")
```

Here is my code when I have tried to use RegEx's

```
import os
import re
import shutil

def test2():
    os.chdir("C:/Users/David/Desktop/Test/MyFiles")
    files = os.listdir(".")
    os.mkdir("C:/Users/David/Desktop/Test/MyFiles2")
    regex_txt = "facebook.com"
    for x in (files):
        inputFile = open((x), "r")
        content = inputFile.read()
        inputFile.close()
        regex = re.compile(regex_txt, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Im guessing that I need a line of code that is something like

```
if regex = re.compile(regex_txt, re.IGNORECASE) == True
```

But I cant seem to get anything to work, if someone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: For future reference, you might find this useful: [Regular Expression HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) for Python 2.7.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

```
import re
if re.match(regex, content):
  blah..
```

You could also use `re.search` depending on how you want it to match.

You can run this example:

```
"""
very nice interface to try regexes: https://regex101.com/
"""
# %%
"""Simple if statement with a regex"""
import re

regex = r"\s*Proof.\s*"
contents = ['Proof.\n', '\nProof.\n']
for content in contents:
    assert re.match(regex, content), f'Failed on {content=} with {regex=}'
    if re.match(regex, content):
        print(content)
```

Comment: thanks, im assuming from your answer that if the regex didnt match anything it would return "None"

Comment: Thats right. Check out http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search to see the difference between using the search() vs the match() function.

Comment: @LWH91 if you wanted `.match()` then your code orginally should have been using `.startswith()` and not `in` :)

Comment: Why not just `if re.match(regex, content):

  blah..`?

Comment: `re.match` can return `None` or an empty string `""` I can't test it currently but I believe checking explicitly for `None` will better allow you to test for the  empty string case.

Comment: why use `is not None` ? doesn't `None` automatcally equals `False`?

Comment: According to the documentation a match object is always truthy: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects

Answer (score 54):

## `if re.search(r'pattern', string):`

Simple if-regex example:

```
if re.search(r'ing\b', "seeking a great perhaps"):     # any words end with ing?
    print("yes")
```

Complex if-regex example (pattern check, extract a substring, case insensitive):

```
search_object = re.search(r'^OUGHT (.*) BE$', "ought to be", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
if search_object:
    assert "to" == search_object.group(1)     # what's between ought and be?
```

Notes:

- Use `re.search()` not re.match.  The match method [restricts to the start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8687988/673991) of the string, a [confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37363575/673991) convention. If you want that, search explicitly with [caret](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax): `re.search(r'^...', ...)` (Or in [re.MULTILINE](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) mode use `\A`)
- Use [raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576583/673991) syntax `r'pattern'` for the first parameter. Otherwise you would need to double up backslashes, as in `re.search('ing\\b', ...)`
- In these examples, `'\\b'` or `r'\b'` is a [special sequence](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) meaning [word-boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44002041/673991) for regex purposes. Not to be confused with `'\b'` or `'\x08'` backspace.
- `re.search()` returns `None` if it doesn't find anything, which is always [falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/673991).
- `re.search()` returns a [Match object](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects) if it finds anything,  which is always truthy.
- even though re.search() returns a Match object (`type(search_object) is re.Match`) I have taken to calling the return value a `search_object`. I keep returning to my own bloody answer here because I can't remember whether to use match or search. It's **search**, dammit.
- a group is what matched inside pattern parentheses.
- group numbering starts at 1.
- [Specs](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html)
- [Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html)

Comment: Very well explained! Must be the accepted answer!

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer because it was very thorough

Answer (score 8):

The REPL makes it easy to learn APIs.  Just run `python`, create an object and then ask for `help`:

```
$ python
>>> import re
>>> help(re.compile(r''))
```

at the command line shows, among other things:

> ## `search(...)`
>
> `search(string[, pos[, endpos]])` --> match object or `None`.
>   Scan through string looking for a match, and return a corresponding
>   `MatchObject` instance. Return `None` if no position in the string matches.

so you can do

```
regex = re.compile(regex_txt, re.IGNORECASE)

match = regex.search(content)  # From your file reading code.
if match is not None:
  # use match
```

Incidentally,

```
regex_txt = "facebook.com"
```

has a `.` which matches any character, so `re.compile("facebook.com").search("facebookkcom") is not None` is true because `.` matches any character.  Maybe

```
regex_txt = r"(?i)facebook\.com"
```

The `\.` matches a literal `"."` character instead of treating `.` as a special regular expression operator.

The `r"..."` bit means that the regular expression compiler gets the escape in `\.` instead of the python parser interpreting it.

The `(?i)` makes the regex case-insensitive like `re.IGNORECASE` but self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

First you compile the regex, then you have to use it with `match`, `find`, or some other method to actually run it against some input.

```
import os
import re
import shutil

def test():
    os.chdir("C:/Users/David/Desktop/Test/MyFiles")
    files = os.listdir(".")
    os.mkdir("C:/Users/David/Desktop/Test/MyFiles2")
    pattern = re.compile(regex_txt, re.IGNORECASE)
    for x in (files):
        with open((x), 'r') as input_file:
            for line in input_file:
                if pattern.search(line):
                    shutil.copy(x, "C:/Users/David/Desktop/Test/MyFiles2")
                    break
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex's shouldn't really be used in this fashion - unless you want something more complicated than what you're trying to do - for instance, you could just normalise your content string and comparision string to be:

```
if 'facebook.com' in content.lower():
    shutil.copy(x, "C:/Users/David/Desktop/Test/MyFiles2")
```

Answer (score 0):

With a running example:

```
"""
very nive interface to try regexes: https://regex101.com/
"""
# %%
"""Simple if statement with a regex"""
import re

regex = r"\s*Proof.\s*"
contents = ['Proof.\n', '\nProof.\n']
for content in contents:
    assert re.match(regex, content), f'Failed on {content=} with {regex=}'
    if re.match(regex, content):
        print(content)
```