# What is the best way to use regex in a for loop while testing for data type?

Tags: python, regex, performance

What is the best way to use regex in a for loop while testing for data type?

For context, I'm looping over large unclean data sets with multiple data types and need to find extensions of strings, if they exist. Small changes to my code, like converting values to string costs me minutes.

I read through this question [Python: How to use RegEx in an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225608/python-how-to-use-regex-in-an-if-statement) but couldn't find a way of testing for a match without first converting to a string.

**Values:**

```
vals = [444444, '555555-Z01']
pattern = re.compile('[-]*[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}$')
# new_vals = [444444, 555555]
```

**Slow method:**  *(2.4 µs ± 93.6 ns per loop)*

```
new_vals = []
for v in vals:
    if type(v)==str:
        if pattern.search(v) is not None:
            new_v = pattern.findall(v)[0].replace('-','')
            new_vals.append(new_v)
    else:
        new_vals.append(v)
```

**Fast method:** *(1.84 µs ± 34.7 ns per loop)*

```
f = lambda x: x if type(x)!=str else pattern.findall(x)[0].replace('-','')

new_vals = []
for v in vals:
    new_vals.append(f(v))
```

**Unsucessful Method:**

```
new_vals = []
for v in vals:
    if ((type(v)==str) & (pattern.search(v) is not None)):
        new_vals.append(v)
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: argh: `if ((type(v)==str) and (pattern.search(v) is not None)):`. `&` doesn't short circuit

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre make that an answer.

Comment: well, I'd vote for a typo instead. And OP isn't clear about the result. What is the point of the third attempt when there's already a "fast" attempt, and should we keep the non-string values, or filter them out?

Comment: Don't use `type(v)` in comparisons. Use `isinstance(v, str)` instead.

Comment: @chepner: testing type is faster when you're sure that the object is of the exact  type

Comment: You can save a couple of instructions by assigning `new_vals.append` to a local variable and using that instead. `append_new_val = new_vals.append ; ... append_new_vals(v)`. Do the assignment before the `for` loop, of course

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `ininstance(v, str)` is consistently faster than `type(v) == str` for `v = "foo"` for me. (~90ns vs ~120ns)

Comment: you're right. I just tested this and it's a tie for me. I've left both in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to beat your attempts using `try/except` blocks but the exception handling seems to take too much time. So much for "better ask forgiveness than permission" ...

Your last attempt is the most promising, if you just change `&` by `and`, because `&` is the logical and and doesn't short circuit.

I'll go for this, in a list comprehension to speed it up slightly more, and drop the `is not None` test which is useless since if `search` succeeds, it returns a regex object, which is truthy:

```
new_vals = [v for v in vals if type(v)==str and pattern.search(v)]
```

or with `isinstance` (same speed, tests subclasses of `str` too):

```
new_vals = [v for v in vals if isinstance(v,str) and pattern.search(v)]
```

Comment: AHA! `if type(v)==str and pattern.search(v):` solves it!

Comment: good. Try the list comprehension approach I'm mentionning. First you'll learn about them (it's worth) and second I think you'll save a few milliseconds more.