# How to use \b word boundary in pandas str.contains?

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, word-boundary

Is there an equivalent when using str.contains?

the following code is mistakenly listing "Said Business School" in the category because of 'Sa.' If I could create a wordboundary it would solve the problem. Putting a space after messes this up. I am using pandas, which are the dfs. I know I can use regex, but just curious if i can use strings to make it faster

```
gprivate_n = ('Co|Inc|Llc|Group|Ltd|Corp|Plc|Sa |Insurance|Ag|As|Media|&|Corporation')
df.loc[df[df.Name.str.contains('{0}'.format(gprivate_n))].index, "Private"] = 1
```

Comment: Sorry, i am using pandas!

Comment: Just use the regular expression word boundary…

Comment: @poke: need to use `r'\b...'` (rawstring). Same old issue that arises with regexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A word boundary is not a character, so you can't find it with `.contains`. You need to either use regex or split the strings into words and then check for membership of each of those words in the set you currently have defined in `gprivate_n`.

Comment: Word boundaries can be caught with `str.contains`, when using `\\b` instead of `\b`, and / or raw strings. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53622104/using-a-variable-within-a-regular-expression-in-pandas-str-contains) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995034/do-python-regular-expressions-from-the-re-module-support-word-boundaries-b).

Comment: @PawelKranzberg: that's actually the same old issue about escaping or raw-string, so use `r\b...`

Comment: This is factually incorrect: `\b` can be used with `str.contains`, you just need raw-string: `r'\b...'`

Answer (score 6):

This is just the same old Python issue in regexes where `'\b'` should be passed either as [raw-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals) `r'\b...'`. Or less desirably, double-escaping (`'\\b'`).

So your regex should be:

```
gprivate_n = (r'\b(Co|Inc|Llc|Group|Ltd|Corp|Plc|Sa |Insurance|Ag|As|Media|&|Corporation)')
```