# Using a variable within a regular expression in Pandas str.contains()

Tags: python, regex, pandas, contains

I'm attempting to select rows from a dataframe using the pandas `str.contains()` function with a regular expression that contains a variable as shown below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["A test Case","Another Testing Case"], columns=list("A"))
variable = "test"
df[df["A"].str.contains(r'\b' + variable + '\b', regex=True, case=False)] #Returns nothing
```

While the above returns nothing, the following returns the appropriate row as expected

```
df[df["A"].str.contains(r'\btest\b', regex=True, case=False)] #Returns values as expected
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps your issue is that you are concatenating the raw strings to a standard string?? Maybe try `fr'\b{variable}\b'`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Both word boundary characters must be inside raw strings. Why not use some sort of string formatting instead? String concatenation as a rule is generally discouraged.

```
df[df["A"].str.contains(fr'\b{variable}\b', regex=True, case=False)] 
# Or, 
# df[df["A"].str.contains(r'\b{}\b'.format(variable), regex=True, case=False)] 

             A
0  A test Case
```

Comment: How would you do this if you had the specify the amount of characters, since that happens with `[0-9]{3}`, for example if you want a pattern of three numbers. Was facing this problem just yet, so just used string concatenation which solved it, and f-string didnt work.

Comment: @Erfan the standard method is to escape the curly braces. If memory serves, that would be {{3}}.

Answer (score 0):

Following command work for me:
`df.query('text.str.contains(@variable)')`

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem when parsing a 'variable' to str.contains(variable).

Try using str.contains(variable, regex=False)

It worked for me perfectly.

Comment: Clearly the opposite as the OP requested.