# Delete rows from pandas dataframe by using regex

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [
            '#x{LA 0.098:abc}',
            '#x{LA abc:0.31}',
            '#x{BC abc:0.1231}',
            '#x{LA 0.333:abc}',
            '#x{CN 0.031:abc}',
            '#x{YM abc:12345}',
            '#x{YM 1222:abc}',
        ]
    }
)
```

I have two list of ids that are needed in order to delete rows based on the postion of "`abc`" from the colon. That is whether `abc` is on the right side of colon or left side.
These are my lists:

```
labels_that_abc_is_right = ['LA', 'CN']
labels_that_abc_is_left = ['YM', 'BC']
```

For example I want to omit rows that contain `LA` and `abc` is on the right side of colon. The same applies for `CN`. I want to delete rows that contain `YM` and `abc` is on the left side of colon. This is just a sample. I have hundreds of Ids.
This is the output that I want after deleting rows:

```
                 a
1    #x{LA abc:0.31}
6    #x{YM 1222:abc}
```

I have tried the solutions of these two answers: [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53622146/10200497) and [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37011978/10200497). And I know that I probably need to use `df.a.str.contains` with a regex. But it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form your criteria into regex first, then do the data filtering:

```
regex_right = r'\b(LA|CN)\b.+\b:abc\b'
regex_left = r'\b(YM|BC)\b.+\babc:\b'
df[~(df['a'].str.contains(regex_right, regex=True) | df['a'].str.contains(regex_left, regex=True))]
```