# BeautifulSoup and regexp: Attribute error

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I try to extract information with beautifulsoup4 methods by means of reg. exp.
But I get the following answer:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

I do not understand what is wrong.. I am trying to:

1. get the Typologie name: 'herenhuizen'
2. get the weblink

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://inventaris.onroerenderfgoed.be/erfgoedobjecten/4778'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
text = soup.prettify()

##block
p = re.compile('(?s)(?<=(Typologie))(.*?)(?=(</a>))', re.VERBOSE)
block = p.search(text).group(2)


##typo_url
p = re.compile('(?s)(?<=(href=\"))(.*?)(?=(\">))', re.VERBOSE)
typo_url = p.search(block).group(2)


## typo_name
p = re.compile('\b(\w+)(\W*?)$', re.VERBOSE)
typo_name = p.search(block).group(1)
```

Does someone have an idea where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change this:

```
## typo_name
block_reverse = block[::-1]
p = re.compile('(\w+)', re.VERBOSE)
typo_name_reverse = p.search(block_reverse).group(1)
typo_name = typo_name_reverse[::-1]
print(typo_name)
```

Sometimes it's easier to just reverse the string if you are looking for stuff at the end.  This just finds the name at the end of your block.  There are a number of ways to find what you are looking for, and we could come up with all kinds of clever regexes, but if this works that's probably enough :)

*update*

However I just noticed the reason the original regex was not working is to use `\b` it needs to be escaped like `\\b` or be raw like this:

```
## typo_name
p = re.compile(r'\b(\w+)(\W*?)$', re.VERBOSE)
typo_name = p.search(block).group(1)
```

Some good followed Q and A here: [Does Python re module support word boundaries (\b)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995034/does-python-re-module-support-word-boundaries-b)

Comment: It works fine. Thanks! And yes, the important is that it is working and get what we want.. But I am still wandering why the regexp in the typo block did not work..

Comment: @francois ah, I just realized it.  To use `\b` you need to do this: `p = re.compile(r'\b(\w+)(\W*?)$', re.VERBOSE)` to make it raw or you need to do `\\b`  similar question with some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995034/does-python-re-module-support-word-boundaries-b