# Removing a string that starts with a substring

Tags: python, string, substring

I want to remove all the words that contain a specific substring.

```
Sentence = 'walking my dog https://github.com/'
substring = 'http'

# Remove all words that start with the substring
#...

result = 'walking my dog'
```

Comment: `re.sub` with a word boundary is the way to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do Python regular expressions from the re module support word boundaries (\b)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995034/do-python-regular-expressions-from-the-re-module-support-word-boundaries-b)

Comment: What code have you written so far? Why doesn't your solution work? Which part of the task is a problem for you?

Answer (score 1):

This respects the original spacing in the string without having to fiddle around too much.

```py
import re
string = "a suspect http://string.com   with spaces before and after"
starts = "http"
re.sub(f"\\b{starts}[^ ]*[ ]+", "", string)
'a suspect with spaces before and after'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple approach that we can use for this.

1. Split the `sentence` into words
2. Find all the works that
3. Check if that word contains the `substring` and remove it
4. Join back the remaining words.

```
>>> sentence = 'walking my dog https://github.com/'
>>> substring = 'http'
>>> f = lambda v, w: ' '.join(filter(lambda x: w not in x, v.split(' ')))
>>> f(sentence, substring)
'walking my dog'
```

Explanation:

```
1. ' '.join(
2.   filter(
3.     lambda x: w not in x,
4.     v.split(' ')   
6.  )
7. )
```

`1` stars with a join. `2` is for filtering all the elements from `4`, which splits the string into words. The condition to filter is `substring not in word`. The `not in` does a `O(len(substring) * len(word))` complexity comparison.

**Note**: The only step that can be sped up is line `3`. The fact that you are comparing words to a constant string, you can use [`Rabin-Karp String Matching`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) to find the string in `O(len(word))` or [`Z-Function`](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/z-function.html) to find the string in `O(len(word) + len(substring))`