# In Python, how to replace either an 'a' or 'an' with a number indicating more than one?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, word-boundary

Note: This question is certainly different from [Does re in Python support word boundaries (/b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995034/do-regular-expressions-from-the-re-module-support-word-boundaries-b). The alluded link seeks an answer for a very simple query for which a cursory glance on any tutorial in Python regular expression would have provided the explanation with examples. My question was using a word boundary around an OR expression and is far from trivial or to be reckoned as duplicate.

I was trying to build a palatable example to demonstrate regex word boundaries. Towards this, I wanted to show how the singular food items ordered by a diet-conscious person are changed for a guzzler and wrote the following program:

```
import re
items_lean = 'a masala dosa, an idli and a mango lassi'
pattern = r'{}'.format('an|a') # Use pattern as dynamic variable in regex
items_fat = re.sub(pattern, 'four', items_lean) # OOPS
print(items_fat)
pattern_fat = r'{}'.format('\ban\b|\ba\b') # Ensure a or an occurs as a word by itself
items_fat_proper = re.sub(pattern_fat, 'four', items_lean)
print(items_fat_proper)
```

I expected the following outputs corresponding to each *print* statement

```
four mfoursfourlfour dosfour, four idli fourd four mfourgo lfourssi
four masala dosa, four idli and four mango lassi
```

But, what I got was:

```
four mfoursfourlfour dosfour, four idli fourd four mfourgo lfourssi
a masala dosa, an idli and a mango lassi
```

Where should the \b factor be placed to get the desired output?

Comment: Why do you use `format` to create your string? Just use `r'\ban\b|\ba\b'`, that would have avoided this error.

Comment: Thanks. That is really simpler and less complicated too. Overambitious to use a Swiss knife, when a simple blade would have sufficed.

Comment: @wiktor-stribizew Thanks for the comment. Added a prefatory note to my question to explain, why it is different from the one you referred to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to satisfy the guzzlers you need to escape the `\b`s or use the raw input format i.e.

```py
pattern_fat = r'\ban\b|\ba\b'
```

I've also removed the superfluous `format` which I suspect caused this confusion!