# Replace only matching words

Tags: python, replace

Have a string,

```
'ANNA BOUGHT AN APPLE AND A BANANA'
```

and want to replace 'AN' and get

```
'ANNA BOUGHT X APPLE AND A BANANA'
```

but simple code:

```
text.replace('AN', 'X')
```

returns:

```
XNA BOUGHT X APPLE XD A BXXA
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do regular expressions from the re module support word boundaries (\b)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995034/do-regular-expressions-from-the-re-module-support-word-boundaries-b)

Answer (score 1):

This code works for every case (begging/middle/end of the string, with or without punctuation marks):

```py
import re

your_string = 'AN ANNA BOUGHT AN APPLE AND A BANANA AN'
replaced_strig = re.sub(r'\bAN\b', 'X', your_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for the word AN, you should use `text.replace(' AN ', ' X ')` with the spaces. That way you'll be replacing only the word and avoiding other occurrences

Comment: That will fail if the string is for example `'AN APPLE'` with no space at the start.

Comment: In this case it works but if 'AN' was at the beggining or the end of the string, it wouldn't be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Let `string = ANNA BOUGHT AN APPLE AND A BANANA`

Then `myList = string.split(' ')`

It will return `myList = ['ANNA', 'BOUGHT', 'AN', 'APPLE', 'AND', 'A', 'BANANA']`

Then you can do the following

`myList[myList.index('AN')] = 'X'`

In case multiple 'AN' is present, we can do the following

```
for i in range(len(myList)):

    if myList[i] == 'AN':

        myList[i] =  'X'
```

Comment: What if there is not exactly one occurrence of `'AN'` (zero or more than one)?

Comment: In that case, we can traverse over the whole list, replacing each `AN` with `X`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions - note the use of `\b` for word boundaries:

```
import re
line = 'ANNA BOUGHT AN APPLE AND A BANANA'
print(re.sub(r'\bAN\b', 'X', line))
```

or a solution without regular expressions (does not preserve the exact amount of whitespace between words, and may not be exactly equivalent if there is punctuation also):

```
line = 'ANNA BOUGHT AN APPLE AND A BANANA'

print(' '.join('X' if word == 'AN' else word
               for word in line.split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

regex is the best way to have such manipulation and even more complex ones, it is a bit intimidating to learn, but once you are done with it it gets really easy

```
import re
text = 'ANNA BOUGHT AN APPLE AND A BANANA'
pattern = r'(AN)'
new = re.sub(pattern,'X',text)
print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

regex is the way - with lookahead and lookbehind

```
import re
line = 'AN ANNA BOUGHT AN APPLE AND A BANANA AN. AN'
pattern='((?<=^)|(?<=\W))AN(?=\W|$)'
p = re.compile(pattern)
print(p.sub('X', line))
```

input: AN ANNA BOUGHT AN APPLE AND A BANANA AN. AN
result: X ANNA BOUGHT X APPLE AND A BANANA X. X