# Regex matching with \b

Tags: python, regex

I dont understand why my string is not matching :

```
re.findall('\bbp\b', 'station bp coucou')
```

According to regex101 it should match ...

Comment: You need "raw strings": try `re.findall(r'\bbp\b', 'station bp coucou')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995034/do-regular-expressions-from-the-re-module-support-word-boundaries-b