# Ternary As A Function Parameter?

Tags: python, ternary

I have a function where I'm searching for regex patterns in sentences and file paths. To do this, I need to chunk the text so that it evaluates full words, not individual characters.

```
def print_word_and_match_fragment(text):

    word_list = text.split('\\') if '\\' in text else text.split()

    patterns = re.compile(r'^[a,A][b,B]{2,3}$')
    d = dict()
    for i in word_list: # Does something
```

To me, it doesn't seem right that I have to make a local ternary variable within the function to do what I need it to do

Why can't it be:

```
def print_word_and_match_fragment(text = text.split('\\') if '\\' in text else text.split() ):

    

    patterns = re.compile(r'^[a,A][b,B]{2,3}$')
    d = dict()
    for i in text: # Does something
```

Is there a way I could just call the ternary as the function parameter or at least something that's equivalent? It doesn't have to be a ternary. Some vague ideas I have was maybe using `**args` or `:=`.

Comment: Because default function values are evaluated when you *define* the function, not when you call it.

Comment: (Also, I think you mean *temporary*, not ternary.)

Comment: `a if b else c` is indeed a ternary expression, but the variable is not a ternary, it's just the list you get back from one of the two `split` calls.

Comment: Also, there's a case to be made that the caller should be responsible for splitting the string on the appropriate character in order to provide a list of words to as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the *default* argument, but it will only be evaluated *once* when the function definition is read
also see ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Instead, you may be able to use `re.findall()` or `re.finditer()` to optionally include `//` and `\b` as a [word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995034/do-regular-expressions-from-the-re-module-support-word-boundaries-b)